# Active directory server v/s Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, domaincontroller

What is an active directory server and what is a domain controller. Are they same . If not whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

they are same thing. Though people, especially in Windows world, would just call them Domain Controller.